# Enable Wsign-compare in MSVC

Tags: visual-c++, warnings, unsigned, signed

I'd like to have a warning similar to `-Wsign-compare` in msvc. E.g. it should trigger for:

```
bool foo(){
  int i = -1;
  size_t j = 1;
  return i == j;
}
```

There is C4389 but that only triggers when `j` is `unsigned`, which I don't really understand: https://godbolt.org/z/Yd5z1P IMO it should trigger for the above.

Is there another warning which works for the above but is minimal in other instances? e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4365?view=vs-2019 is to agressive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an (apparently) undocumented warning **C4388** that will be shown for your code, which is very similar to [the documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4389?view=vs-2019) **C4389**.

The following code, compiled with the `/W4` switch generates each of these two warnings:

```cpp
#pragma warning(default:4388)
#pragma warning(default:4389)
bool foo()
{
    int i = -1;
    unsigned j = 1;
    size_t k = 1;
    bool a = i == j; // warning C4389: '==': signed/unsigned mismatch
    bool b = i == k; // warning C4388: '==': signed/unsigned mismatch
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Yes this works, thanks! However C4389 is another warning (although very similar) which triggers when `j` is `unsigned`. C4388 seems to be undocumented. I assume they had C4388 first but replaced it by a less aggressive C4389, but who knows...

Comment: I see [C4388](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/c4388?view=msvc-160) as documented now...